# Not able to commit data using CopyManager using Spring boot C(Auto Commit is enabled)

Tags: java, spring-boot, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to use copy command to copy data using STDIN to postgresql using spring boot and JPA. But the copyIn command is getting executed and returning the expected number of records but unable to see the data in database.

```
public void copyData(){
    PGConnection pgConnection =null;
    CopyManager copyManager = null;
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    CSVWriter csvWriter = null;
    long noOfRecords = 0L;
    try {
      pgConnection = dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(PGConnection.class);
      copyManager = pgConnection.getCopyAPI();
      fileWriter =new FileWriter(new File("bulk_data.csv"));
      csvWriter = new CSVWriter(fileWriter);
      List<String[]> strList= IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(this::getChargeDtl)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
      csvWriter.writeAll(strList);
      csvWriter.flush();
      csvWriter.close();
      fileWriter.close();
      BufferedReader bufferedReader =new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bulk_data.csv"));
      noOfRecords = copyManager.copyIn(
        "COPY test(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) FROM STDIN  DELIMITER ',' CSV header",
        bufferedReader);
      bufferedReader.close();
      ((BaseConnection)pgConnection).close();
    }catch(SQLException seq){
      seq.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException ioe){
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
      System.out.println(noOfRecords);
    }
  }
```

I am not getting any exceptions once the execution gets completed.

Comment: Sounds as if you are missing a `commit()` call somewhere

Comment: AutoCommit is enabled so not using any explicit commit() call